# How to remove unity3d game engine from Ubuntu (and its dependencies)?

Tags: package-management, games, development

I have installed it from .deb package. I can't find packages that I should remove.

Comment: where did you download this `.deb` from?

Comment: What's the name and source of the Deb file? It should contain the name of the package to remove.

Comment: @Ron, http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've got it:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-editor -y
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, but maybe explain (for people who don't know) what the `-y` flag does?

Comment: @ConfusedMr_C It means yes. In process of installing/deleting of some package system will ask you: "are you sure you want  delete/install it", so you can tell "yes" in advance, if you don't want wait when it will ask you.

Comment: How did you find the package name?